# Check if a string contains any integers in SQLite

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, where-clause

I have a database with fields for movie_title, imdb_rating, and genre. How can I use SQLite to select movies that have numbers in the title? I'm trying this code, which isn't working:

```
SELECT * FROM movies
WHERE movie_title like '%[0-9]%';
```

I've looked at other similar questions, and the answers look something like the above, but I can't figure out what about my code is going wrong. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLite you could do this with [`glob`](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like)- unless `like`, it supports character classes:

```
select *
from moveis
where movid_id glob '*[0-9]*'
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I wasn't able to find this glob solution anywhere else for SQLite. I suppose studying syntax for SQLite is the best way to understand this and similar techniques.